# Слетает вёрстка при подключении jsapi

Tags: css, yandex-maps-jsapi

При подключении `<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">` слетает вёрстка некоторых элементов на странице. Очевидно, совпадают какие-то имена классов у меня на страннице и в API. Можно ли где-нибудь узнать, какие имена там используются?

Comment: вы откройте инспектор в браузере и посмотрите, куда ваши стили деваются. в картах все стили с префиксом по номеру версии карта начинаются, так что вряд ли они вам что-то могут ломать.

Comment: Все стили яндекс карт идут с префиксом версии JS API, например .ymaps-2-1-74-*